# MySQL 5.1: Check MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'USER 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password''

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a MySQL user on a Solaris server. here is the command I am using:

```
ALTER USER 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';
```

But I recevied the following error.

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
> near 'USER 'admin'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password
> BY 'password'' at line 1

What am I get this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I can't find any reference to any `ALTER USER` statement in [MySQL/5.1 documentation](http://download.nust.na/pub6/mysql/doc/refman/5.1/en/user-account-management.html).

Comment: I tried CREATE USER 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password', but got the same error.  Actually, the MySQL version is  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.72

Answer (score 1):

`ALTER USER` was introduced in MySQL 5.6, which has been generally available since 2013. This statement is not supported in older versions of MySQL.

You can create a user with the `CREATE USER` statement. In fact, that's the correct statement even in current versions of MySQL. I'm not sure why you're trying to use `ALTER USER` if you want to create a new user.

If you want to change the password for an existing user, use the `SET PASSWORD` statement.

Really, you should just upgrade. The version of MySQL you are using passed its end-of-life in 2013.

Comment: I also tried  CREATE USER 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH  mysql_native_password BY 'password',  but got the same error. all I want is to create a user that can use Workbench to connect to the MySQL server. Can it be mysql_native_password related?

Comment: @hdew The error message (which cannot be literally the same) should mention the exact word where MySQL finds difficulties.

Comment: By all means, keep trying to guess the syntax. Don't bother to read the documentation. You're bound to figure it out eventually.